# What is this limit called? Is it a different kind of derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative, infinitesimals

(first I should notice you this is not something I can look up in a textbook, because I'm learning partial derivatives, alike I do with most Maths, as a hobby. If something below is wrong, blame the internet and please let me know)

I know I can take a mixed partial derivative of a multi-argument function, for expl.:

$$
w = f(x; y; z) = x^2 y+ y^2z + xz^2\\
\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\ \partial y} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2xy+z^2)= 2x = ^*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2yz+x^2)
$$
(* = double check)

But that's taking 2 partial derivatives. What If I want more than one variable to vary at once?
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f(x+h;y+h;z)-f(x;y;z)}{h}\right)=\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{(x+h)^2 (y+h)+(y+h)^2 z+(x+h)^2z^2-(x^2 y+ y^2z + xz^2)}{h}\right)=\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{(x^2+2xh+h^2)(y+h)+(y^2+2hy+h^2) z+(x+h)z^2-(x^2 y+ y^2z + xz^2)}{h}\right)=\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{2hxy+h^2y+hx^2+h^2x+h^3+2hyz+h^2z+hz^2}{h}\right)=\\
=\lim_{h \to 0} \left( 2xy+hy+x^2+hx+h^2+2yz+hz+z^2\right)
=2xy+x^2+2yz+z^2
$$

Note: I took a while to write this, and only now I notice that the result of the above is the sum of $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$, while the mixed partial in the beginning is its multiplication

Nonetheless, the question remains: what is this limit called? Can it be seen as another type of derivative? What are its applications? Is there a notation in which I can write it such as the one for other derivatives?

Thank you readers in advance (and for reading, my questions are not usually short).

Comment: The "hello" was deleted for some reason. Is it automatic? I don't think it happens in StackOverflow. Also, feel free to  ask for any information you think I should add to the post.

Comment: @GitGud, yes but multiplication (even of derivatives) is commutative (at least from what I read). Besides I made a double-check. Thanks for the reply anyway (a propósito, acho que deves escrever em inglês).

Comment: Check [Schwarz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). The (partial) derivatives need not commute. They do here as a consequence of the aforementioned theorem.

Comment: Notice that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \left( \frac{f(x+h;y+h;z)-f(x;y;z)}{h}\right) &= \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h;y+h;z) - \left(f(x;y+h;z) - f(x;y + h;z)\right) - f(x;y;z)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h;y+h;z) - f(x;y+h;z)}{h} + \frac{f(x;y + h;z) - f(x;y;z)}{h}\\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},
\end{align*}
and I think the last equality here should hold *at least* in reasonable cases. This is also what happened in your example, as you noted. I don't think there's any special name for this derivative, as I think we would simply see the sum.

Comment: @GidGud, thanks for the link, but it says there is no problem, as this function is continuous.

Comment: @Stahl, thanks for the effort, but I already checked, and as the [referred link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) said, your "reasonable cases" are continuos functions. I'll mark those comments as helpful as soon as I can.

Comment: @JMCF125 Indeed. I just wanted to point out that the way you wrote it you mixed up the order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For, what you're looking at is a special case of a *directional derivative* of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. a derivative along some direction (vector) $d$. In general, those are defined as $$
  f_d(x) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+td) - f(x)}{t} \text{,}
$$
where $x,d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. You looked at the special case $d=(1,1,0)$, i.d. you let the first and the second argument vary simultaneously and the third not at all.

Sometimes (or often, depending on what functions you usually work with), the directional derivatives are a *linear* function of the direction. In that case, the function is simply called *differentiable*. In other words, you then have that $$
  f_{u+v}(x) = f_{u}(x) + f_{v}(x) \text{.}
$$
If that is so, then it's sufficient to know e.g. the derivatives in the direction of all the axes to compute *any* directional derivative. Since the derivatives in the direction of the axes are simply the ususal partial derivatives, this means that in this case $$
  f_{d} = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
  \quad\text{assuming that}\quad
  d = (d_1,\ldots,d_n).
$$
Which is exactly what you found - you computed $f_{(1,1,0)}$ and found it to be $1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + 1\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + 0\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

If this works, it's custom to arrange the partial derivatives into a vector (or matrix, if the function also produces multiple values). *The* derivative of a function $f \,:\, \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is thus the vector $$
  \frac{df}{dx} = f' = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right).
$$
Similarly to the one-dimensional case, you can then approximate $f$ around $x$ by (note that $\cdot$ is the scalar product!) $$
  f(x+d) \approx f(x) + f'(x)\cdot d \text{.}
$$

Note that this doesn't always work - one example is $$
  f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} &\text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\
    0                           &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$
at $(0,0)$. Both partial derivatives are $0$ at $(0,0)$, yet the derivative in direction $(1,1)$ isn't. This function therefore is said to be non-differentiable at $(0,0)$, even though the partial derivatives *do* exists. But they don't convey *all* the information there is to know about the function's behaviour around $(0,0)$.

Comment: You want $d=(1,1,\color{red}{0})$ in the first part.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yup, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Also, it isn't *quite* the directional derivative as you define it, since the directional vector isn't a unit vector. Rather, it is a scalar multiple of the directional derivative (specifically, multiplied by $\sqrt2$, the length of $d$ in this case).

Comment: @CameronBuie Yeah, that was on purpose, otherwise I'd be lying if I said it was *linear* in the direction, no? That implies that scaling the direction must scale the derivative...

Comment: True, in order to be linear in the direction, we must allow the direction vectors to be non-unit. Still, that isn't how directional derivatives are generally defined (at least, I've never seen them defined that way). Those will generally be defined by $$f_d(x):=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+td)-f(x)}{t\lVert d\rVert}$$ for non-zero vectors $d\in\Bbb R^n$, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Rather than a special case, then, I'd say it's a variation of the directional derivative.

Comment: @CameronBuie I've seen both definitions, and Wikipedia lists both too (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), they even list mine first ;-). It really depends on what the ultimate goal is. Here, since the point I wanted to make was *exactly* the linearity, defining them like you would IMHO only complicate things.

Comment: (+1) Huh. How about that? Thanks for the link!

Comment: So it's a derivative in direction, huh? I'll search more about them and mark this as answer as soon as I do.

Comment: @JMCF125 *Along* a direction, I'd rather say, but yes.